# Can't install steam from software center: "Additional software packages are missing or not installable"

Tags: software-center, steam

When I try to install steam on the `Ubuntu software center`, I get this error:

> This error could be caused by required additional software packages
>   which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a
>   conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be
>   installed at the same time.

Comment: Please add more details: Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 ? PC specs ?

Answer (score 1):

I actually just ran into this, did you install Steam from the PPA before? If you did remove the PPA (open Software Sources, Other Source tab, and remove the steam sources) and uninstall steam (open a terminal [ctrl + t] and type "sudo apt-get remove steam" without the quotes)